# javascript i++ vs ++i

Tags: javascript, operators

In javascript I have seen `i++` used in many cases, and I understand that it adds one to the preceding value:

```js
for (var i=1; i<=10; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

But what happens when I do this:

```
++i;
```

And is it any different using the `--` operator (besides of course that it's subtraction rather than addition)?

Comment: Might be useful for you to know that ++i is often referred to as PREFIX notation and i++ as POSTFIX notation. It works the same in many other languages.

Answer (score 265, accepted):

The difference between `i++` and `++i` is the value of the expression.

The value `i++` is the value of `i` before the increment. The value of `++i` is the value of `i` after the increment.

Example:

```
var i = 42;
alert(i++); // shows 42
alert(i); // shows 43
i = 42;
alert(++i); // shows 43
alert(i); // shows 43
```

The `i--` and `--i` operators works the same way.

Comment: most of the time, ++i is ever so slightly faster.
this may be system-dependent, but in theory it should.

http://jsperf.com/plusplusi-vs-iplusplus

Comment: @aelgoa: Most of the time the difference is within the margin error, and the rest of the time there is no consistent result. If you don't use the value of the expression, theoretically there should be no difference at all, as the compiler should optimise it to the same operation.

Comment: @aelgoa +1, as this has nearly full coverage in other languages, ++i is always a best practice unless a particular language has explicitly worse performance. I've heard people argue it is negligible, but not always. For instance with server-side javascript  not just generating a page, you may well be looping quickly over a one liner millions of times. This can cut your per-loop overhead by ~1/2 which can matter on one-liner loops quite a lot.

Comment: Guffa is correct here. http://jsperf.com/ppi-vs-ipp-forloop when I run this test and it shows i++ being faster in a for loop, but not by enough to be significant. While ++i may be faster in other languages, I think it's safe to say javascript optimizes the operation to be the same.

Answer (score 75):

`++variable` increments the variable, returning the new value.

`variable++` increments the variable, but returns the old value.

`--variable` decrements the variable, returning the new value.

`variable--` decrements the variable, but returns the old value.

For example:

```
a = 5;
b = 5;
c = ++a;
d = b++;
```

`a` is 6, `b` is 6, `c` is 6 and `d` is 5.

If you're not using the result, the prefix operators work equally to the postfix operators.

Comment: if you're using the result as an array index, you can also offset it by 1 initially, for prefixing =]

Comment: I think this is the best answer. clear and easy to understand

Comment: I was super confused the first time I entered in i++ into a recursive function and it became and infinite loop XD. This is a good explanation

Answer (score 14):

I thought for completeness I would add an answer specific to the first of the OP's question:

One of your example shows the i++ / ++i being used in a for loop :

```
for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
  alert(i);
}
```

you will get 1-10 in your alerts no matter which you use. Example:

```js
  console.log("i++");
  for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
    console.log(i);
  }
  console.log("++i");
  for (i=1; i<=10; ++i) {
    console.log(i);
  }
```

Paste those into a console window and you can see that they both have the same output.

Comment: True, but do that in reverse: console.log("i--");
for (i=10; i--;) {
  console.log(i);
}
console.log("--i");
for (i=10; --i;) {
  console.log(i);
}

Comment: Why? The ability to use ++i in a for loop would def be desirable behavior.

Answer (score 11):

One case all these answers fail to mention is what happens when `i++` and `++i` are used in operations with other numbers. While the whole “*`i++` is before, `++i` is after*” concept is easy to grasp when the expression is by itself, it gets much more confusing when you start combining statements. See Examples C and D below.

```
// Example A
var i = 42;
var a = i++; // equivalent to `var a = i; i = i+1;`
console.log(a); // 42
console.log(i); // 43

// Example B
var i = 42;
var b = ++i; // equivalent to `i = i+1; var b = i;`
console.log(b); // 43
console.log(i); // 43

// Example C
var i = 42;
var c = i++ * 2; // equivalent to `var c = i*2; i = i+1;`
console.log(c); // 84
console.log(i); // 43

// Example D
var i = 42;
var d = ++i * 2; // equivalent to `i = i+1; var d = i*2;`
console.log(d); // 86
console.log(i); // 43
```

Notice that in Example C, the `i++` is not evaluated until *after* multiplication and the assignment of `c`. This counters the misconception that “`i++` should be evaluated first in the order of operations.” So in other words the statement `i++ * 2` actually calculates `i * 2` *before* it increments `i`.

Answer (score 10):

`i++` = Use the value of i in statement then increase it by 1 
`++i` = Increase the value of i by 1 then use in statement.

Answer (score 9):

It determines whether the increment happens before or after the value of the variable is used.

```
var j = 2;
console.log(j++);   // 2
console.log(j);     // 3

var k = 2;
console.log(++k);   // 3
console.log(k);     // 3
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var i = 0;
console.log(i++); // 0
console.log(++i); // 2
```

Comment: It would be better to use two variables here to illustrate the difference. Examples should not do more than one thing.

Answer (score 6):

`++variable` : Increment variable before using variable
`variable++` : Increment variable after using variable

I figured it could be useful to include an answer with a snippet to confirm how they behave in a `for` loop.

Just to verify in your browser that there's really no difference when using a `++i` versus a `i++` in the for loop declaration.

And throwing `--i` versus `i--` while we're at it.

```js
console.log("-- with looping --");

console.log("using ++i in a for loop");
for (var i=1; i<=3; ++i) {
  console.log(i);
}

console.log("using i++ in a for loop");
for (var i=1; i<=3; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}

console.log("using --i in a for loop");
for (var i=3; i>=1; --i) {
  console.log(i);
}

console.log("using i-- in a for loop");
for (var i=3; i>=1; i--) {
  console.log(i);
}

console.log("-- without looping --");
var i = 1;
console.log("i: "+ i);
console.log("i++: "+ i++);
console.log("i: "+ i);
console.log("++i: "+ ++i);
console.log("i: "+ i);
console.log("--i: "+ --i);
console.log("i: "+ i);
console.log("i--: "+ i--);
console.log("i: "+ i);
```