# Javascript: Calculating the average of an array using for-loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

Like the title suggests, what I need to do is calculating the average of an array using for-loop. And by average I mean `(a+b+c+d+e)/5=average.`

That's what I need to do in text, since I'm new at javascript I don't quite know how to execute this. Any ideas?

Also, if you think this question doesn't belong here or is stupid, please direct me to somewhere where I can find this information, I'm just trying to learn here.

```
function test(arr) {


}
```

Comment: lol fail, my bad, fixed it

Comment: Blind, blind, blind...

Comment: see this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359907/array-sum-and-average

Comment: Here is a good post
[Array Sum and Average][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359907/array-sum-and-average

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate over the values, sum them up, and return the value of `sum`, divided by the number of entries.

```
function test (arr) {
  for (var i=0,sum=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    sum += arr[i];
  }
  return sum / i;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
function average(items) {
  var sum = 0;
  var count = items.length;
  for (i=0; i<count; i++) {
    sum += items[i];
  }
  return sum/count;
}
```

Or if you want `average()` to be available as a method on arrays:

```
Array.prototype.average = function() {
  var sum = 0;
  var count = this.length;
  for (i=0; i<count; i++) {
    sum += this[i];
  }
  return sum/count;
}
```

Usage:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].average(); // 3
```

Comment: @AndrewP Inside the loop, we add the values one-by-one into an accumulator (`average` variable). After the loop we divide the sum with the number of amounts.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a post with the response to your answer.

[Array Sum and Average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359907/array-sum-and-average)

Also check this link about for loop in Javascript:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
var nCtrr = 0, nSum = 0, nAvg = 0;
var arNum = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
for ( nCtr in arNum ) {

    nSum += arNum[ nCtr ];
    nCtr += 1;

}
nAvg = nSum/arNum.length;
alert( nAvg );
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/STNLH/)

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion, none of the answers here check for length === 0, you'll be dividing by zero in some situation in the future.  I suggest you always check mathematical boundary conditions.  The related article had one response which caught that (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18234568/987044).

Here is another example if you want to be safe.
http://jsfiddle.net/ledlogic/syn74/

```
var nothing = null;
var empty = [];
var items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]; // 20 sider
function average(items) {
    if (!items) {
        return 0;
    }
    var sum = 0,
        count = 0;
    // for large arrays, faster to go down.
    for (var count = items.length, i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sum += items[i];
    }
    return count ? sum / count : 0;
}

alert(nothing + ":" + average(nothing) + "\r" + empty + ":" + average(empty) + "\r" + items + ":" + average(items) + "\r");
```

The [math.js](http://mathjs.org/) library, [mean.js](https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs/blob/master/lib/function/statistics/mean.js) also does array length checking.