# Calculating the average of object properties in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, average

I'm trying to calculate the average temperature of one week, but I do not quite know how I would do this. I've tried out some things but the end result would be either 'NaN' or 'Infinity'. Definitely doing something wrong here..

Here's the code I need to work with:

```
var temperatures;

temperatures = new Array();

temperatures["monday"] = 23.5;
temperatures["tuesday"] = 22.3;
temperatures["wednesday"] = 28.5;
temperatures["thursday"] = 23.5;
temperatures["friday"] = 22.3;
temperatures["saturday"] = 28.5;
temperatures["sunday"] = 29.5;
```

I got it working when the arrays were like [0], [1] instead of Strings containing the days, but I don't know how to do it like above. Also if you have any suggestions please try to keep the code basic as surprisingly enough 'advanced code' isn't too appreciated in my class for some reason.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the code you were currently using to get the average, even if its returning the wrong result.

Comment: It seems to be already explained here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359907/array-sum-and-average

Comment: You're mixing arrays (accessing values by integer index) and objects (accessing values by key)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The average is just the total  divided by number of temperatures

```
var temperatures = {},
    length = 0,
    total  = 0;

temperatures["monday"] = 23.5;
temperatures["tuesday"] = 22.3;
temperatures["wednesday"] = 28.5;
temperatures["thursday"] = 23.5;
temperatures["friday"] = 22.3;
temperatures["saturday"] = 28.5;
temperatures["sunday"] = 29.5;

for (var day in temperatures) {
    total += temperatures[day];
    length++;
}

var average = total / length;
```

Note that arrays don't have named keys, only objects do

Comment: isn't `day` a global variable now? (I'm not sure - it's just what my Netbeans code highlighter is showing) If so, wouldn't it be better to also declare it with the other vars on top?

Comment: @Cold_Class - good eyes, just declaring it in the for loop solves that.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
 var temperatures;
    var sum = 0,
        count = 0;
    temperatures = new Array();
    
    temperatures["monday"] = 23.5;
    temperatures["tuesday"] = 22.3;
    temperatures["wednesday"] = 28.5;
    temperatures["thursday"] = 23.5;
    temperatures["friday"] = 22.3;
    temperatures["saturday"] = 28.5;
    temperatures["sunday"] = 29.5;
    
    for (var prop in temperatures) {
        if (temperatures.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            count++;
            sum += temperatures[prop];
        }
    }

    var average = (sum / count);
    alert(average);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try Object instead of Array, if you wish Key Value pair.

```
var temperatures;

temperatures = new Object();

temperatures["monday"] = 23.5;
temperatures["tuesday"] = 22.3;
temperatures["wednesday"] = 28.5;
temperatures["thursday"] = 23.5;
temperatures["friday"] = 22.3;
temperatures["saturday"] = 28.5;
temperatures["sunday"] = 29.5;

alert(temperatures["sunday"]);
```

you will get key value pair js object,
you can use it for Average:

```
var sum = 0;
for(key in temperatures)
{
   sum  = sum+temperatures[key];
   console.log(temperatures[key]);
}
alert(sum/7);
```

[Check this Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/patelbharat001/7erfgtL5/1/)

Comment: What you trying to achieve. Have you read question carefully?

Comment: @Manwal Sorry for the answer without example, but i guess questioner  wants to access variable with key instead of index, and do average of that.Now i had updated my answer with Demo.

Answer (score 0):

I believe traversing causing problem for you. here is solution

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nzoxypt2/)

```
var count=0,total=0;
for(t in temperatures)
{
    total = total+temperatures[t]
    count++;
}
alert(total/count);//average
```