# How to call a reduce function in another function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I am trying to call this reduce function:

```
users.reduce(function (acc, obj) { return acc + obj.age/3; }, 0);
```

in this function:

```
function computeUserAverageAge(users) {};
```

to test this array of objects for the average of these "age" values:

```
const users = [{
           name: 'Brendan Eich',
           age: 56,
         }, {
           name: 'Linus Torvalds',
           age: 48,
         }, {
           name: 'Margaret Hamilton',
           age: 81,
         }];
```

I am thankful for your help and patience!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating the average of object properties in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930547/calculating-the-average-of-object-properties-in-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move it with in the function and return the result.

**Note:** instead of using `3` use `users.length` instead.

I also think that mathematically, you should divide by the number after you add them up, and not each iteration.

```js
const users = [{
  name: 'Brendan Eich',
  age: 56,
}, {
  name: 'Linus Torvalds',
  age: 48,
}, {
  name: 'Margaret Hamilton',
  age: 81,
}];

function computeUserAverageAge(users) {
  return Math.round(users.reduce((acc, obj) => acc + obj.age, 0) / users.length);
};

console.log(computeUserAverageAge(users))
```

Comment: Thanks, and if I wanted to round the answer I could put:                                                        function computeUserAverageAge(users) {
  return Math.floor(users.reduce(function(acc, obj) { return acc + obj.age / users.length; }, 0);) };  ?

Comment: use `Math.round()`, `Math.floor()` or `Math.ceil()`, see my above edits.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to return the result of the `reduce`. Might as well use arrow functions for brevity:

```js
const computeUserAverageAge = users => users.reduce((a, { age }) => a + age, 0) / 3;
console.log(computeUserAverageAge(
  [{
    name: 'Brendan Eich',
    age: 56,
  }, {
    name: 'Linus Torvalds',
    age: 48,
  }, {
    name: 'Margaret Hamilton',
    age: 81,
  }]
));
```

Comment: 185 isn't an average of the 3. You forgot to divide

Comment: `users.length` would be better.