# Total cost function in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

i am having issues (very lost) in making a code that me and my friend were given to create.

So I am suppose to compute and return the average of all values in a given array named customerBalance, the array holds the amount of "what customers owe my business" (I dont own a business) and each item in the array holds the "customers balance", i also have to use a for() to process the array and calculate the average and divide by customerBalance length, and finally return the average.

Here is my code so far

```
function average() {
    customerBalance
    for(i=0,i++)
      sum(customerBalance)
    total=sum/5

return average;
```

I know that this is COMPLETELY wrong, I am not sure on how i start typing the array, please don't be harsh I would really like to know how to do this.

Thank you and have a great day

Comment: I just realalized that what i have so far did not indent and properly form when i copy and pasted it onto here, I am sorry that makes it more difficult to read.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array Sum and Average](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359907/array-sum-and-average)

Answer (score 0):

```
function average(customerBalance) {
    if (customerBalance.length == 0) { // Prevent division by zero later
        return 0;
    }
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < customerBalance.length; i++) {
        total += customerBalance[i];
    }
    var average = total/customerBalance.length;
    return average;
}
```

You have many problems:

1. The parameter to a function goes in the parenthese after the function name, not the next line.
2. Your `for()` syntax is all wrong. You need to put the initialization, repetition test, and increment separated by semicolons.
3. There's no `sum()` function in Javascript. And even if there were, you would need to assign the result to a variable.
4. When you calculate the average, you're putting it in `total`, but then you're returning `average`, which is the variable that contains the function, not the average you calculated.

Other recommendations:

1. Don't hard-code the array size, use `array.length` to get it.
2. Always put braces around the body of `for`, `if`, `while`, etc. even if they're just one line.
3. Local variables should be declared with `var`.

Comment: Thank you very much Barmar, where you put //Prevent division by zero later, would the "//" go to the next line as a comment? Inserting it the line before return 0;?

Comment: Everything after `//` on a line is a comment and is ignored. Do you know even the most basic thing about Javascript syntax?

Comment: I know that the comment line is ignored and aware that (at least for the course im in) is required for every 3 lines of code, I was just wondering if that is necesarry there or after the return 0;. And no i am not to familiar with it at all very intrigued and think it's cool and would like to learn more

Comment: It doesn't matter where you put the comment. It's totally ignored, it's just for the benefit of human readers.

Comment: Still missing a local declaration of the `i` variable.