# Calculating The Average Value Of Array Elements In Java Script?

Tags: javascript

I Want To Calculate Average Value Of Array Elements Using Java Script. I am an beginner in Java Script, So Please Give me the easiest & understandable code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33470127/3993662

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all items in your array are numbers, loop through them, and sum them. Once you have a sum of all items, divide this figure by number of items (`your_array.length`) and then you'll get your average.

Show your existing code, what you have done so far?

Not tested, pseudo code:

```
var array = [1, 6, 43, 2, 8];
var sum = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(array[i]);
}

if (array.length > 0) {
    console.log('Average is ' + (sum / array.length));  
}
```

Comment: Check my answer. It's working.

Comment: I'm Unable To See Output Though I Given The Same Code In <script> Tag

Comment: The output won't be displayed on the screen. I used `console.log` so open your console. If you want to display average value on the screen use `document.write`.

Comment: It Worked! Thanks Alot For Your Help...I'm Having More Doubts in javascript..I will get back here for help!

Comment: Glad I could help. Please, up vote my answer if it was useful. Thanks.