# Get mean of all elements at a given index across multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, reduce

I have about 300 arrays that each have 100 arrays of x and y values. I want to get an array of 100 mean for y values of the 300 arrays. What is the best way to do this? I believe I should use some sort of reduce but am a little lost.
Here is what I have so far:

```
let yval = cohort.map((d, i) => {
    let bin = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) {
            return i;
        })
        .rollup(function(d) {
            return d;
        })
        .entries(d);

    return bin;
});

console.log(yval);
```

'cohort' is an array of objects. I want to isolate the 'bins' array in each cohort object. Each of these are 117 elements long. For each bins[i], I want to get the mean of [i] from all of the bins. I want to basically turn the array of 300 arrays of 117 into one array of 117 means. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

D3 already has a method named [d3.mean](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#mean), which:

> Returns the mean of the given array of numbers

Therefore, if you want to get the mean for each inner array, all you need is this (where `data` is your original array):

```
var arrayOfMeans = data.map(d => d3.mean(d));
```

Here is a basic demo:

```js
var data = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
  [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
];

var arrayOfMeans = data.map(d => d3.mean(d));

console.log(arrayOfMeans)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

However, your data structure is not very clear right now: the description above the snippet (*"I have about 300 arrays that each have 100 arrays of x and y values"*) is different from the description below the snippet (*"'cohort' is an array of objects. I want to isolate the 'bins' array in each cohort object. Each of these are 117 elements long."*)! It's very confusing...

So, supposing that you have an array of arrays and that in each inner array you have two values, `[x, y]`, this is how you can use `d3.mean` for the two means, one for the `x` value and other for the `y` value:

```
var arrayOfMeans = [d3.mean(data.map(d => d[0])), d3.mean(data.map(d => d[1]))];
```

Or, if you don't like literals:

```
var arrayOfMeans = d3.range(2).map(d => d3.mean(data.map(e => e[d])));
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var data = [
  [1, 100],
  [2, 200],
  [3, 300]
];

var arrayOfMeans = [d3.mean(data.map(d => d[0])), d3.mean(data.map(d => d[1]))]

console.log(arrayOfMeans)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the help! The data structure is a little weird. I am using the cohort in a separate visualization so I am pulling a subset of that data to use for this. Right now I am testing some options out but I'll do some reworking. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

There's already an answer to how to calculate the mean of an array in JS:

[Finding the average of an array using JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544371/finding-the-average-of-an-array-using-js/29544442)

You could use the function defined in that answer, and map it across the array of arrays. For example:

```
var result = cohort.map(cohortElement => cohortElement.bin).map(/*function declared in other StackOverflow answer*/)
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected use below option of ForEach and array reduce method

1. First creating loop for 300 arrays using array.ForEach method
2. Inside loop for each array , I am using reduce to find the mean

```js
var sampleArr = [];// sample array for testing 
var meanList = [];// final Mean list array
for (var i=0; i< 301; i++){
  sampleArr[i] =[]
   for (var j=0; j< 2; j++){
   sampleArr[i].push({
     x:i,
     y:i+1
   })
}
}

getMean = arr => {
  arr.forEach(e => {
    let sum = e.reduce(function(a, c) {
      console.log(a, c);
      return a.y + c.y;
    });
    meanList.push(sum / e.length);
  });
};

getMean(sampleArr)

console.log(meanList);
```

I have created sample array of length 300 and each with 2 arrays for testing

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/eMXNMZ?editors=1010