# How to get the average of two numbers?

Tags: arrays, math, average, prompt, microsoft-appstudio

```
var thing1 = prompt("what is a number")
var thing2 = prompt("what is a number")

alert(Math.min(thing1,thing2));
```

I am able to get the minimum of the two members.
How do I change this to give the average of the two numbers asked?

Comment: Average means you need to add your numbers together and divide by how many numbers you added together.

Comment: There is no inbuilt average method in javascript.
you need to write your own method.which is very straight forward ..This link wold help you of how u can do it better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359907/array-sum-and-average

Comment: Try Googling "How do I get the average of two numbers". Hint: It doesn't involve taking their minimum.

Comment: I know what an average is.... I'm asking how I write the code to get that? I am using AppStudio. I'm trying to learn and I don't know how to do this on my own, aka why I came to this website!!

Comment: `(thing1+thing2)/2` if `thing1` and `thing2` are numeric types.

Comment: Is this `JavaScript`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that gets an average:

```
function average(){
  var a = arguments, l = a.length;
  if(l){
    for(var i=0,n=0; i<l; i++){
      n += a[i];
    }
    return n/l;
  }
  return false;
}
// horrible idea to use prompt and alert
var prompt1 = prompt('enter a number');
var prompt2 = prompt('enter another number');
alert(average(prompt1, prompt2));
```

Comment: `return false` o_O