# Bell Curve with django is not working

Tags: django, highcharts

I am trying to create bell curve using django and highcharts but its not looking like i expected,
Here is the image what exactly i want[image]

currently I'm working on this

```
var data = [ 2.7, 2.7, 3, 3.4, 3.1, 2.3, 3, 2.5, 2.6, 3, 2.6, 2.3,
2.7, 3, 2.9, 2.9, 2.5, 2.8, 3.3, 2.7, 3, 2.9, 3, 3, 2.5, 2.9, 2.5, 3.6,
3.2, 2.7, 3, 2.5, 2.8, 3.2, 3, 3.8];

Highcharts.chart('container', {

title: {
    text: 'Bell curve'
},

xAxis: [{
    title: { text: 'Data' }
}, {
    title: { text: 'Bell curve' },
    opposite: true
}],

yAxis: [{
    title: { text: 'Data' }
}, {
    title: { text: 'Bell curve' },
    opposite: true
}],

series: [{
    name: 'Bell curve',
    type: 'bellcurve',
    xAxis: 1,
    yAxis: 1,
    baseSeries: 1,
    zIndex: -1
}, {
    name: 'Data',
    type: 'scatter',
    data: data,
    marker: {
        radius: 1.5
    }
   }]
 });
```

[Click here to see](https://jsfiddle.net/8q1t3mwb/)

```
the problem which I'm facing are following:
1. How to remove scatter 
2. How to display average point on curve.
3. How to display gradient like given in image.
```

Comment: I have edited the question, now can you help me to solve any of the given probelm.

Comment: i just need hint on how to calculate one,i will do other one by myself

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions is simple after reading the [API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/) docs for Highcharts.
1. To remove the scatter series from view you do set its `visible` and `showInLegend` properties to `false`:

```
{
    name: 'Data',
    type: 'scatter',
    data: data,
    marker: {
      radius: 1.5
    },
    visible: false,
    showInLegend: false
  }
```

2. How to display average point on curve is a bit more complex. First you need to get the average. This you can do via javascript (taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10624256/33727) really neat code):

   var sum = data.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; });
   var avg = sum / data.length;

Then you need to show this on the actual chart. There are many options but a scatter point or Highstock flag is probably the best option.

3. To display a gradient is really simple. You use the `color` property of the series and set the gradient options and set the colors to your liking:

   `{
       name: 'Bell curve',
       type: 'bellcurve',
       xAxis: 1,
       yAxis: 1,
       baseSeries: 1,
       zIndex: -1,
       color: {
           linearGradient: {
               x1: 0,
               y1: 0,
               x2: 1,
               y2: 0
           },
           stops: [
               [0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
               [1, 'rgb(200, 200, 255)']
           ]
       }
   }`

Comment: thanks for the help now only problem which i'm facing is with plag placement,can you help me to put place flag on bell curve. [Link]https://jsfiddle.net/8q1t3mwb/4/

Comment: As it's specified in **docs**: *[...] there is one point at the top which is the mean of the bell curve.* (https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/bell-curve-series). Its **x** position is saved in `mean` property of the series object. **Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/h5zdjtbh/