# Take the average of an array items

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Try to get average of values. I have json data going inside that, grabbing the array and using the average function on it. But error returns...

> TypeError: arr.reduce is not a function

It's from first `console.log(myArray)` as per screenshot below. and second console.log with avg function, not working...

[image]

```js
data() {
    return {
        myArray:[],
    }
},    
methods: {
    avgArray: function(){
        const sum = arr => arr.reduce((a,c) => (a + c));
        const avg = arr => sum(arr) / arr.length;
        this.estates.forEach((a, index) => {
            this.myArray = a.m2_price;
            console.log(this.myArray);
        });

        console.log(avg(this.myArray));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the json sample?

Comment: you cannot use addition in combination with array or object in such manner

Comment: You need `this.m2 = total / this.estates.length;` (and I'd move that line below the loop) (also, json is a text format that looks like JS object literals, there's no such thing as a JSON object)

Comment: What does `estates` look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array Sum and Average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359907/array-sum-and-average)

Comment: @adiga when i do console.log(this.m2) array items return no problem with that.

Comment: Again, I don't know what `this.estates` looks like. Please share a sample of `this.states` and a clear problem statement on what you're trying to do. As it's written, this is not a [mcve]

Comment: Which version of chrome are you running?

Comment: I am running Chrome 71 @DhananjaiPai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
avgArray: function(){
    const sum = arr => arr.reduce((a,c) => (a += c),0); // add equals and init with 0
    const avg = arr => sum(arr) / arr.length;
    this.myArray = this.estates.map(a =>  a.m2_price)
    console.log(avg(this.myArray));
}
```

You were setting this.myArray as a value and not an array. You could've either pushed the m2_price or map it like above

Reduce function only exists on arrays. Clearly you were logging this.myArray and getting integers. Hence the error.

Answer (score -1):

That is what reduce is for

```js
const average = array => (array && array.length) ? (array.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item, 0) / array.length) : undefined;


console.log(average([1,2,3,4,5,6]));
```

export the average function from a file called average.js

Applied to your situation

```
import { average } from 'pathToYourIncludeLibrary/average';

data() {
    return {
        myArray:[],
    }
},    
methods: {
    avgArray: () => average(this.myArray)
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but I can't apply your code to mine... could you revise it?

Comment: Export that average function from a file called average.js "export const average = ..." ... being the rest of the function and then import it into your component

Comment: The function is called average but you need to read the average property of the returned value to get it :/

Comment: It is just an internal variable on the accumulator, it is still part of the function.

Comment: Edited it to get rid of the compound accumulator, no need to calculate the average on each iteration.