# How do I get average of one array and compare it with a value

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

So I want to return true if `myScore` is higher than `classScore` average but it keeps returning false.
This is what I came up with.

```
function compareScore(classScore, myScore) {

  var classAverage = 0;

  for(var i = 0; i < classScore.length; i++){
    classAverage = (classAverage / classScore.length) + classScore[i];
  };

  if(myScore > classScore){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(compareScore([20,20,20],70))
```

Comment: See [How to compute the sum and average of elements in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10359907/215552)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare `classAverage` not the array `classScore`. And also the correct way to calculate average is get sum of array and then divide it by `length` of array.

In below case you don't need to use `if` `else` just simply `return` the result of logical operation.

```js
function compareScore(classScore, myScore) {
  let classSum = 0;

  for(var i = 0; i < classScore.length; i++){
    classSum += classScore[i];
  };
  let classAverage = classSum/classScore.length
  return myScore > classAverage;
}

console.log(compareScore([20,20,20],70))
```

Another way of doing that is to use `reduce()`

```js
const compareScore = (classScore, myScore) => classScore.reduce((ac, a) => ac + a, 0)/classScore.length < myScore

console.log(compareScore([20,20,20],70))
```

Comment: quick note on your example that uses reduce, you could use `classScore.reduce((ac,a, i, arr)=> ac + (a/arr.length), 0)` to get the average without needing to do the division at the end.

Answer (score 0):

you could youse Array.reduce() to get the sum and go from there.

```
function compareScore(classScore, myScore) {
      var sum = classScore.reduce((previous, current) => current += previous);
      var average = sum / classScore.length;

      if(myScore > average){
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }

    console.log(compareScore([20,20,20],70))
```

Comment: Two things: The compound assignment `+=` isn't necessary since the function's return value is what's used, not `current`, so `+` is sufficient there. Secondly, you need to specify an `initial` value of `0` so that empty arrays won't throw an exception. Of course, both of these points have already been addressed in the existing answer, so yours doesn't add anything helpful.