# Average in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

Then I need a function that gets the average high. Here is what i did:

```
    function getAverageHeight() {
        let total_height = 0;
        let average_height = statues.length;

        if (statues.length > 0) {
            for (let i = 0; i < statues.length; i++) {
                let statue = statues[i];

                total_height += isNaN(statues.height) ? 0 : statue.height;
            }
        average_height = (total_height / statues.length).toFixed(2);
         }
       return average_height;
       }
```

But when i test it i got NaN as as response not the average. What I did wrong here? Can someone give a clue?

Comment: `isNaN(statues.height)` should be `isNaN(statue.height)`. Also, initializing the average with the length of the array doesn't make sense.

Comment: by usig functional programming you would certainly not run into such mistake

Comment: You could simplify your average function by adapting this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10624256/1024832

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of the solutions here are pretty good, but there are edge cases with `isNan` like `true` and `''`. It's safer to use `parseInt` first. Here's a solution that tosses out edge cases and returns the average.

```
let statues = [];
function createStatue(name, city, heightInMeters) {
  statues.push({
    name,
    city,
    heightInMeters
  });
}

// create statues + edge cases inputs
createStatue("Number", "New York", 46);
createStatue("Decimal", "Florence", 5.17);
createStatue("String", "Florence", '123');
createStatue("True", "Boston", true);
createStatue("Empty", "New York City", '');


function getAverageHeight() {
  // Filter out bad cases here
  const filteredStatues = statues.filter((x) => {
    let num = parseInt(x.heightInMeters);
    return !isNaN(num);
  });

  const total = filteredStatues.reduce((acc, x) => {
    return acc+parseInt(x.heightInMeters);
  }, 0);
  return (total/filteredStatues.length).toFixed(2);
}

console.log(getAverageHeight());
```

EDIT:
The OP has provided the original code. Looking at it there are some oddities.

```
heightInMeters: heightInMeters,
  isLongerThan: function (other_statue) {            
    return this.highInMeters > other_statue.hightInMeters;
```

It looks like there are several typos here and the code shouldn't run.

Comment: Good one!, forgot about how NaN could cause trouble

Comment: @EugenSunic Thanks. I looked at your code and it's good. The reason it doesn't work is the original code has `heightInMeters` not `height`

Comment: What i need here with this code is:
1. Write a function named createStatue that expects to receive three arguments:
name, location, and heightInMeters.

Comment: I will put all that i need with this code above in the original post.

Comment: @ErickMatt That function is at the top of the code provided... it's called `createStatue`

Comment: @JosephCho Yes, but there is a lot more. I've put all the quest that i have in the post. If tried your code but then i lost isTallerThan. Didn't know how to adapt it to your code.

Comment: @ErickMatt `isTallerThan` never worked to begin with. There are typos in your function. Please keep in mind Stackoverflow is a place to debug not assist with homework.

Comment: @ErickMatt anyways, this is the best and most stable answer I believe

Comment: @JosephCho Sure, i know that is not a place for homework. I'm learing and writing and i know that my code might be with bugs. That is why i asked a question about the average, the rest i placed here just in case someone needs to see it full. It might have other errors but i'm my focus was on that. What i need to do, i shared just because to let you know that i have others issues and that is why your shared code for the first part wouldn't solve my issue. Sorry if it looks like 'homework', trying my best here to fix bugs.

Answer (score 2):

You want to be using

```
isNaN(statue.height)
```

Rather than

```
isNaN(statues.height)
```

Comment: That typo wouldn't cause it to result in `NaN` though. It would cause it to result in `"0.00"`. Something else is causing `NaN`.

Comment: I did that and now i'm getting 0.00 as a result

Comment: @ErickMatt try my answer

Answer (score 1):

Create a function which accumulates objects in an array each time it is called.

Create a separate average function which takes that accumulated array and returns the average results of height if height is a number

```js
let statues = [];
function createStatue(name, city, height) {
  return statues = [...statues, {
    name,
    city,
    height
  }]
}
// call functions to populate array
createStatue("Statue of Liberty", "New York", 46);
createStatue("Christ the Redeemer", "Rio de Janeiro", 30);
createStatue("David", "Florence", 5.17);
createStatue("Little Mermaid", "Copenhagen", 1.25);
createStatue("Winged Victory", "Paris", 2.44);
createStatue("Venus de Milo", "Paris", 2);


function getAverageHeight() {
  const total = statues.reduce((acc, x) => {
    if (!isNaN(x.height)) {
      acc.counter += 1
      acc.sum += x.height;
    }
    return acc;
  }, {
    sum: 0,
    counter: 0
  })
  return (total.sum / total.counter).toFixed(2)

}

console.log(getAverageHeight())
```

Comment: That seems a good solution but the fact is that i need to create a variable named statues and assign to it an array. This array should contain this six objects that are created by calling the createStatue function. Can i adapt it somehow?

Comment: check the answer again

Comment: Still getting a NaN as answer. I'll post my whole code so maybe it gets easier to see to problem

Answer (score 1):

You are needlessly setting the default value of average_height, and you accidentally typed "statues" instead of statue.

```
function getAverageHeight() {
    let total_height = 0;
    let average_height = "0.00"; // ⭐ This will be returned when statues.length <= 0

    if (statues.length > 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < statues.length; i++) {
            let statue = statues[i];
            total_height += isNaN(statue.height) ? 0 : statue.height; // ⭐ You meant statue.height, not statues.height
        }
        average_height = (total_height / statues.length).toFixed(2)
    }
    return average_height;
}
```

Or you could use [Array.reduce](https://mdn.io/array.reduce), like this:

```
let getAverageHeight = () => (statues.reduce((a, b) => {
    a += b.height;
    return a
}, 0) / statues.length || 0).toFixed(2)
```

Comment: Got a 0.00 as an answer.

Comment: Could you elaborate please?