# JavaScript Array calculate average returns NaN

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, reduce

I have an array with this format:

```js
let array = [{length:0},{length:5},{length:5},{length:10},{length:5}]

let sum = array.filter(x=>x.length).reduce((a,b)=>a.length + b.length, 0)

let count = array.filter(x=>x.length).length

console.log(sum,count,sum/count)
```

What I need is to filter the values > 0 and calculate an average based on those, but it always gets NaN for `sum` and consequently for the average I need. I started from this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62372003/803358).

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the filtered items and get the sum by taking the `length` property. The reson for getting `NaN`, you take a number and get the property `length` from `a`, which does not exists. And while using `undefined` as value for adding, you get `NaN` as sum.

Later divide by the length of the filterd array.

```js
let array = [{ length: 0 }, { length: 5 }, { length: 5 }, { length: 10 }, { length: 5 }],
    items = array.filter(x => x.length),
    sum = items.reduce((sum, { length }) => sum + length, 0),
    length = items.length,
    average = sum / length;

console.log(sum, length, average);
```

An approach by using an object for `sum` and `count` and a single loop.

```js
let array = [{ length: 0 }, { length: 5 }, { length: 5 }, { length: 10 }, { length: 5 }],
    { sum, count } = array.reduce(
        (o, { length }) => (o.sum += length, o.count += !!length, o),
        { sum: 0, count: 0 }
    ),
    average = sum / count;

console.log(sum, count, average);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is how the way you use the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function.

```js
let array = [
  { length: 0 },
  { length: 5 },
  { length: 5 },
  { length: 10 },
  { length: 5 }
];

let sum = array.filter((x) => x.length).reduce((a, b) => a + b.length, 0);
let count = array.filter((x) => x.length).length;
console.log(sum, count, sum / count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const array = [{ length: 0 }, { length: 5 }, { length: 5 }, { length: 10 }, { length: 5 }];
let count = 0;
let sum = 0;
for (const item of array) {
  if (item.length) {
    sum += item.length;
    count++;
  }
}
console.log(sum / count);
```