# Average Sub-Array Data from JSON

Tags: json, vue.js, axios

I would like to get the average of data in sub-array from json by axios call

[JSON Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOo93.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compute the sum and average of elements in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359907/how-to-compute-the-sum-and-average-of-elements-in-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `.reduce()` like this:

```
averageVote(data) {
  let total = data.votes.reduce((accumulator, vote) => {
    return accumulator += vote.vote;
  }, 0);
  let count = data.votes.length;
  return total / count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just parse this answer (`JSON.parse`), iterate over votes, sum vote values and then divide the sum by length of votes table. Simple as that.