# Calculate average of value in array of object

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose I have an array of object as,

```
const BookDetails = [
  { bookName: 'Harry Pottar', readingTime: 10663 },
  { bookName: 'Harry Pottar', readingTime: 10986 },
  { bookName: 'kaptura Tech', readingTime: 7034 }
]
```

For this I tried solution as,

```
const avgInvoiceProcessingTime = Math.round(((readingTime.map(a => a.Time).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / 1000)));
```

But it doesnot give average.

I want to count all the readingTime and divide by length of BookDetails array, but having trouble adding all the reading time.

Comment: _“But it doesnot give average.”_ - it should give you an _error_ first of all, because there is no variable `readingTime`.

Comment: You want `BookDetails.map(a => a.readingTime).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)` to sum up all those `readingTime` values, and get `28683`. Why you’d want to divide it by 1000 then, if you want the average - unclear.

Comment: Because it is in ms and want to convert it to second.

Comment: Okay, but then you still need to divide by the _number_ of items you summed up there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compute the sum and average of elements in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359907/how-to-compute-the-sum-and-average-of-elements-in-an-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using `reduce`. Add all `readingTime` and divide it by the `length` of the `readingTime`.

`readingTime` is property of an object and it is not an array.

You can only use `reduce` on `Array.`

You need to divide the total(addition of readingTime) with `BookDetails.length`

```js
const BookDetails = [{
    bookName: "Harry Pottar",
    readingTime: 10663
  },
  {
    bookName: "Harry Pottar",
    readingTime: 10986
  },
  {
    bookName: "kaptura Tech",
    readingTime: 7034
  },
];

const result =
  BookDetails.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.readingTime, 0) /
  BookDetails.length;
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

you were right in using reduce, but you needed to use it on the array:

```js
const BookDetails = [
  { bookName: 'Harry Pottar', readingTime: 10663 },
  { bookName: 'Harry Pottar', readingTime: 10986 },
  { bookName: 'kaptura Tech', readingTime: 7034 }
]

const sum = BookDetails.reduce((acc,cur) => acc + cur.readingTime,0);
const count = BookDetails.length;
const avg = sum / count;

console.log(avg)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` to calculate the sum of all the `readingTime` and also convert them into seconds. And then finally divide the result by the no. of items in the array.

```js
const BookDetails = [
  { bookName: "Harry Pottar", readingTime: 10663 },
  { bookName: "Harry Pottar", readingTime: 10986 },
  { bookName: "kaptura Tech", readingTime: 7034 },
];

BookDetails.reduce((r, o) => r + o.readingTime / 1000, 0) / BookDetails.length;
```

Comment: @SivaPradhan Please check if this solves your problem, let me know if you have any issues.