# Trying to override a variable inside a function and get an error: "Block-scoped variable '...' used before its declaration.ts(2448)"

Tags: typescript, function, scope, declaration

I'm writing a *typescript* function that accepts a numeric array (i.e., `type: number[]`) and calculates its mean. In addition, I want to account for when the input array might contain some `null` values. To this end, I added an argument, that when set to `true`, tells the function to remove `null`s before calculating the mean.

But I can't figure out the proper way to do this, as I can't override the input within the function.

Here's my code for `calcMean()`

```js
function calcMean(arr: number[], nullRemove: boolean = true): number {
    if (nullRemove) { // if TRUE, which is the default, then throw out nulls and re-assign to `arr`
        const arr: number[] = arr.filter((elem) => elem !== null);
    }
    // then simply calculate the mean of `arr`
    return arr.reduce((acc, v, i, a) => acc + v / a.length, 0); // https://stackoverflow.com/a/62372003/6105259
}
```

I then get an error:

> Block-scoped variable 'arr' used before its declaration.ts(2448)

I also tried using `let` in addition or instead of `const` but it didn't solve the problem.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What should happen when `nullRemove` is `false`?

Comment: @jsejcksn if `nullRemove` is `false` then the IF block shouldn't be executed, thus `return arr.reduce((acc, v, i, a) => acc + v / a.length, 0);` is the only thing the function does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options for you:

1. Don't *redeclare* it, just reassign it:

```
function calcMean(arr: number[], nullRemove: boolean = true): number {
    if (nullRemove) { // if TRUE, which is the default, then throw out nulls and re-assign to `arr`
        arr = arr.filter((elem) => elem !== null);
        // ^^^ No `const` here
    }
    // then simply calculate the mean of `arr`
    return arr.reduce((acc, v, i, a) => acc + v / a.length, 0); // https://stackoverflow.com/a/62372003/6105259
}
```

Some folks believe reassigning parameters is poor style (I'm not one of them provided the function is quite small as in your case, but I understand the argument), so alternatively:

2. Assign to a different variable:

```
function calcMean(arr: number[], nullRemove: boolean = true): number {
    // Remove `null` if requested
    const a = nullRemove ? arr.filter(elem => elem !== null) : arr;
    // then simply calculate the mean of `arr`
    return a.reduce((acc, v, i, a) => acc + v / a.length, 0); // https://stackoverflow.com/a/62372003/6105259
}
```

Comment: I like that you addressed the topic of parameter immutability. Also: using inverted ternary conditionals objectively increases cognitive load when reading source code.

Comment: @jsejcksn - Re the inversion: The purpose there was to avoid making it hard to find the `arr` at the end. But sure, it could absolutely be `const a = nullRemove ? arr.filter(elem => elem !== null) : arr;` I waffled on it when writing it. You're probably right I should swap it around.

Answer (score 1):

The code in your question doesn't currently allow for `null` values to be included in the `number[]` parameter.

I like for my code to be explicit about what's happening, so in the case where there might be `null`s mixed in the array of `number`s, I would explicitly convert them to `0` in the case that they are not removed:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/PQKhAIFEEMGMAtwDsCuAbN4CmasFsskAXcASwGdtSj4sAncAez2qKwBMmHZGkA3em05FG4AAzgQwALAAoAGYoksIqV7h40JO1wA5dGgBq0NCiyUAFNDp0AXODpZo7XmgCe4C6jwAjeuAAfZAMASgBtAF0AGiYWEgBecCI6MxD7bz86SPAAbzlwBywiFDokWOpwAH58gvBrOgA6eVI0NjoLCz4TVPsu0ywySgz-eIA+cD6zcABCeMTUDBCagvt6hrxoAAdO7oGxid3wOfmDKvFwXt2QgG45AF85OUVlVXVYE1gAWScyqxt7RzOVweLwoXz+IILNDhaLBDAAJXwjAERySKSwaWC4IYeVkBR4SHIJGGdEoiU02j0BmM-XIfzoMShiLwyIxtzxhWKpSxmXIDUc7BQsCwHXIYMZISO4zFeHAAGpkJLgDz6HzcEgAOY0dkPWSPWTAZUAFXMRDkBPIjFwDWg5HIggs7zQXx+FjCUJiAEYYgBmGIAdhiAE4IpLjuAAKw3cCGpgAa3NvEt1tt9roREdH2+WjdHvAnrEXt9AeDsPkJntYbmkejscYCdkQA)

```ts
/** Each null element is either omitted or converted to 0 */
function handleNullValues (arr: readonly (number | null)[], omit = true): number[] {
  return omit ?
    arr.filter((value): value is number => value !== null)
    : arr.map(value => value === null ? 0 : value);
}

function calcMean (arr: readonly (number | null)[], nullRemove = true): number {
  const numbers = handleNullValues(arr, nullRemove);
  return numbers.reduce((sum, n) => sum + n) / numbers.length;
}


// Test
console.assert(calcMean([null, 1, 3, 7, 9]) === 5); // ok
console.assert(calcMean([null, 10, 1, 3, 7, 9], false) === 5); // ok
```

---

Edit: Updated in response to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71334478/trying-to-override-a-variable-inside-a-function-and-get-an-error-block-scoped/71335407?noredirect=1#comment126095514_71335407).

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=13&ssc=58&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAhgGwgWQKYqQChQCciAuRI3AEwTQE9F8wQBbAI2yMQB9Fm00ASgDaAXUHlm7TogDeAWABQiRGmxRkccBoC8iAAwBuJSspQQRJMSIA6YDDRRO+fADd0IbBMTu0nxDAAznysHFw6AHxyJiqaYIEaQQByoTJ6UHQADthwwD4e2Ig6xYgA5FJhpcbKsTB5+MmpRIKa2ogA1HoAjNWxFOoWSI3SRL2IAL6CNpRUIBDYLoGsADR8LZGISywda4gA9K1gUNXjSmeKewcAKtgJShAIgXBqNiiBgZxQ+KgYOHj4wi6qwAzKsAOyrACc4iKJQArIJDPsDnAANb3R7PbCvd6fb7oLC4MAA-hoVZAxCgxAQxDQ9bwxHIxBopRAA)

```ts
function calcMean (arr: readonly (number | null)[]): number {
  let count = 0;
  return arr.filter((value): value is number => {
    const isNumber = typeof value === 'number';
    if (isNumber) count += 1;
    return isNumber;
  }).reduce((sum, n) => sum + n) / count;
}


// Test
console.assert(calcMean([1, 3, 7, 9]) === 5); // ok
console.assert(calcMean([null, 1, 3, 7, 9]) === 5); // ok
```

Comment: Thanks. Converting `null` to `0` is mathematically problematic because those `0`s are still counted in the denominator. Thus, dropping `null` before calculation is the only sensible pre-step.

Comment: @Emman In that case (`null` values should always be removed), the additional argument is not necessary since there is no alternate logic branch needed. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my case for typescript, I also received the message

> Block-scoped variable 'filename' used before its declaration.ts(2448)

```
exportAsExcel () {
   const format = 'xlsx'
   const exportSelectedOnly = true
   const filename = 'test'
   this.$refs.grid.exportTable(format, exportSelectedOnly, filename)
}
```

Solved by

```
const format = 'xlsx' as string
const exportSelectedOnly = true as boolean
const filename = 'test' as string
```