# In a basic javascript for loop, what is the difference between ++i and i++ and which should I use

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

In a basic for loop, what is the difference between

```
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4];
for(var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; ++i) {
   console.log(i);
}
```

and

```
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4];
for(var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
   console.log(i);
}
```

(The difference is just in the `++i` and `i++`)

I see both used everywhere. It seems to me they both produce the exact same result. If this is the case, is there a preference for either one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867876/javascript-i-vs-i

Comment: In that case I'm sorry I was not clear about my question. I am aware about the basic difference between i++ and ++i. My question is specific to the for-loop. Does a choice for either one influence the for loop specifically? Maybe gives optimized performance?

Answer (score 3):

There's no difference. The only difference between pre-increment and post-increment is if you're assigning the result to something; pre-increment assigns the new value, post-increment assigns the old value.

Comment: To be clear, by "assigning", you must mean "using the value in an expression".

Answer (score 1):

pre-increment (++i) adds one to the value of i, then returns i; in contrast, i++ returns i then adds one to it, which in theory results in the creation of a temporary variable storing the value of i before the increment operation was applied.

There change i++ to ++i to optimize.

Comment: +1, because that's one of the big differences. That said, I suspect any half-decent optimizer will turn `i++` into `++i` in these cases. I personally use `++i` because the `++` operator is the increment operator, so the whole thing reads "increment `i`."

Answer (score 0):

According to [ECMA Script 5.1 Standard Specification for `for` loop](http://es5.github.io/#x12.6.3),

> f. If the second Expression is present, then.
>
> i. Let ***incExprRef*** be the result of evaluating the second Expression.
>
> ii. Call GetValue(incExprRef). (**This value is not used.**)

The expressions in alteration part are evaluated, but their values are ignored. So, `++i` and `i++` will not make any difference here.

Also, [`++i`](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.4) and [`i++`](http://es5.github.io/#x11.3.1) are evaluated almost the same. So, I hardly think there will be any difference in performance front as well.