# What is the difference between 2 code (loop for javascript)?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between 2 code (loop for javascript) ?

```
<script>
for(x=0;x<5;x++)
{
alert(x);
}
</script>
```

AND

```
<script>
for(x=0;x<5;++x)
{
alert(x);
}
</script>
```

i tested the result will be same.

But in w3school advice like this

```
for(x=0;x<5;x++)
```

Could you please tell me. i can use `for(x=0;x<5;x++)` and `for(x=0;x<5;++x)` too ?

Comment: First `x` is zero and in the end of loop assign `++`. Second code `x`starts in `1` because first asign `++`  and then read the value

Comment: `i tested the result will be same.` In this case, maybe. But both are different codes

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Have you tested it. I too thought the same. But seriously the results are same.

Comment: @mongmong There is a answer already in stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867876/javascript-i-vs-i

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I don't need to test it. I know that in this case the result is the same, but it doesn't be the same in another situations. Try to write a while loop with this two variants and maybe you'll obtain different results, depending on the code you'll write

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude But the question is about, which one we have to use in for loop the post increment/pre increment, because both will yield the same result at this context/

Comment: I don't try to answer this exactly question, I try to comment what's the difference between both assignments

Answer (score 1):

In for loop it's same. Difference is in example like this:

```
var x = 5;
alert(x++); // alerts 5 and then increments
```

.

```
var x = 5;
alert(++x); // increments and then alerts 6
```

Answer (score 0):

The `i++` and `++i` differ only in the value they return, which is ignored when written in the 3rd field of the `for` loop. In this case, they're exactly the same thing.

The difference between them can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445706/post-increment-and-pre-increment-concept).