# Working with variables within javascript console.log function

Tags: javascript, variables, logging, console

I am seeing sort of strange behaviour with javascript. I am new to this language, but from what I can see, if you increment a variable (or change it in any way) from within a console.log() method, this actually globally changes the variable.

```
var a = 0;

console.log(a); //prints 0

console.log(a++); //prints 0, a becomes 1
console.log(a++); //prints 1, a becomes 2
console.log(a++); //prints 2, a becomes 3

console.log(a); //prints 3
```

Is this something peculiar to javascript? I would have thought that the variable would not get affected globally and that the last print statement would show a as being 0.

Comment: Related: [javascript i++ vs ++i](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6867876/5894241)

Comment: using `a++` is using a `post-increment` operation.. I don't see anything wrong here

Comment: Yes that is perfectly normal.  The console runs with the same scope as the `window`, or the page you are on.  You're not running those bits of code in isolated scope, so they affect the page and its contents.

Comment: Its not the increment operator I have a problem with. It is the fact that statements from within a console.log() function can globally modify a variable.

Comment: You're not using it "within" `console.log`, whatever that means. Your code is equivalent to `var b = a++; console.log(b);`. Not sure why you think inlining it into a function call would somehow isolate `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ++ will affect the variable, if you want to do it only for log purposes, you must use +1 , this is how it works in javascript ^^

```js
var a = 0;

console.log(a); //prints 0

console.log(a+1);
console.log(a+1);
console.log(a+1);

console.log(a); //prints 0
```