# interval missing first item

Tags: javascript, html

I've written some js to the word displaying in `#changingword` loops through several different words. It mostly works however when it first loads it skips through the second word so it goes from 'design' straight to 'e-commerce solutions', without showing the 'development'. After the first loop it works correctly. My code is below.

The html:

```
 <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
    <h1>Creative Development</h1>
    <h2 id="changingword">Design</h2>
  </div>
```

The JS:

```
<script>
(function(){
    var words = [
        'Development',
        'E-commerce Solutions',
        'Optimisation',
        'Support',
        'Design'
        ], i = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        $('#changingword').fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).html(words[i=(i+1)%words.length]).fadeIn("slow");
        });
    }, 1500);

})();
</script>
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Replace your `i=(i+1)` with `i++`.

Comment: Don't replace (i+1) with i++, use ++i and you have to adjust initializing i. Check my post for more info how to use it correctly and what is the difference between prefix and postfix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in here:

```
$('#changingword').fadeOut(function(){
    $(this).html(words[i=(i+1)%words.length]).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

You're updating `i`, **then** using the resulting value in the calculation.

Update `i` *after* using it:

```
$('#changingword').fadeOut(function(){
    $(this).html(words[i%words.length]).fadeIn("slow");
    i++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that on first pass through the words[i=(i+1)%words.length] will be equivalent to words[1] not words[0].

You can increment but return the preincremented value by doing

```
$('#changingword').fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).html(words[i++%words.length]).fadeIn("slow");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be tricky to do increment and use result in the same line, you need to be sure how the expression is evaluated.

Change:

```
words[i=(i+1)%words.length]
```

to:

```
words[i=(++i)%words.length]
```

And set `i=-1;` to start.

Now the `(++i)` makes sure i is incremented by 1 immediately, before rest of the expression, that's why we need to start at -1. From there it's all good.

It's an alternative to already posted answer if you wanna keep the expression with increment instead breaking the increment to another row.

General difference of `++i` and `i++` is same across many languages so it's worth looking into it:

[SO post with quick explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867876/javascript-i-vs-i)

[SO post with better explanation but in diff language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031326/what-is-the-difference-between-prefix-and-postfix-operators)