# Protractor - How to get all cells from one column and sum them when the Grid has id="0-0" for rows-Columns

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I am validating a drill down process in the portal i am testing, for this my script is doing:
Read the value from the first row of a table and click at this value (there is a link for certain cells that perform the drill down to the detail page)
To click at this particular cell I am using it's ID:

```html
<table id="transHistTable" class="table table-hover  table-bordered table-striped dataTable no-footer" style="width: 100%" role="grid" aria-describedby="transHistTable_info">
<thead>
<tbody>
<tr role="row" class="odd">
<td id="0-0" class="ng-scope">31 Jul 2018</td>
<td id="0-1" class="ng-scope">RandomText0</td>
<td id="0-2" class="ng-scope">RandomText1</td>
<td id="0-3" class="ng-scope">EmptyValue</td>
<td id="0-4" class="ng-scope">Value I Click And Save it</td>
```

So for this table I am clicking directly to the row 0 column 4 since my data and my filters will always bring only one row, but then, comes my problem....
When the drill down is performed I never know how many rows I will have since it depends of user operations.
I need to perform a validation to compare the sum of all the values from the table displayed after the drill down with the value captured from table "transHistTable" row 0 column 4

This is the values I get after performing the Drill Down:

```html
<table id="transHistDetailTable" class="table table-hover  table-bordered table-striped dataTable no-footer" style="width: 100%" role="grid" aria-describedby="transHistDetailTable_info">
<thead>
</thead>
<tbody><tr role="row" class="odd">
<td id="0-0" class="ng-scope">Site</td>
<td id="0-1" class="ng-scope">Date</td>
<td id="0-2" class="ng-scope">Time</td>
<td id="0-3" class="ng-scope">I</td>
<td id="0-4" class="ng-scope">value 1</td>
<td id="0-5" class="ng-scope">value 2</td>
<td id="0-6" class="ng-scope">value 3</td>
<td id="0-7" class="ng-scope">12</td>
</tr></tbody>
</table>
```

So what I would like to do is reading all the rows (could be 0,1,2,3,4,5...) saving the value that is stored in Column 7 then after this is done, perform a sum and then comparing with the value I have saved from the first table.

My code is this one:

```
            var rowstransHistDetail = element(by.id('transHistDetailTable')).all(by.tagName("tr"));

            rowstransHistDetail.count().then(function(rcount){
                //In case only 1 row is displayed
                if (rcount < 3)
                {
                    element(by.id('0-7')).getText().then(function(valueQty){  
                        expect(valueQty).toEqual(600)
                    })
                }
                else
                {
                    var tempValue
                    for (i=0; i < rcount; i++)
                    {
                        element(by.id(i+'-7')).getText().then(function(valueQty){

                            tempValue = Number(tempValue) + Number(valueQty)
                        })
                    }

                    expect(tempValue).toEqual(600);
                }
            });
```

But when I execute this, gives me a undefined value

Any ideas how to solve this please?

Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are incrementing a value in a loop before execution.
See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6867907/6331748

Should bee `i++` instead of `++i` in a loop.

Drop me a line if I'm wrong.

===========================

Edited:
Here's some code from my side:

```
var expectedCells = element.all(by.css('#transHistDetailTable tr td:nth-of-type(5)'));
var currentSum = 0;
expectedCells.each((eachCell) => {
    eachCell.getText().then((cellText) => {
        currentSum += Number(cellText);
    });
}).then(() => {
    expect(currentSum).toEqual(600);
});
```

Sorry, but wasn't able to test it. I only want to share a main idea and elaborate it.

`expectedCells` are all `id=n-4` cells. We go through all elements and get text from them, change to the number type and add to current value. Aftermath we do an assertion.

It also looks that `if` statement is not necessarily.
Let me know how it works.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, yes that was one of the problems, I edited the answer and the code looks cleaner now, the problem that I still have is to correctly sum the values, I can retrieve all values from the column (not sure if in the best way or not) but I cannot sum them, already tried the parseInt since Im getting strings but still with NaN error or ManagedPromise::13803 {[[PromiseStatus]]

Comment: Because you just define  `var tempValue`,  not init it. so the value of `tempValue` is `undefined`, then `Number(tempValue)` is  `Number(undefined)` which return NaN. And  `NaN + Number(..)` still return NaN

Comment: Hi @Kacper thank you very much! worked perfectly, just had to change the column number being captured, have a good day!

Comment: Hi @yong Even doing that was giving me an error, I was not doing it properly but kacper's answer solved my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two options for your issue:

1) using `element.all().reduce()`

```
let total = element
    .all(by.css('#transHistDetailTable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(8)'))
    .reduce(function(acc, item){
        return item.getText().then(function(txt) {
            return acc + txt.trim() * 1;
        });
    }, 0);

expect(total).toEqual(600);
```

2) using `element.all().getText()` and `Array.reduce`

```
let total = element
    .all(by.css('#transHistDetailTable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(8)'))
    .getText(function(txts){ //txts is a string Array
        return txts.reduce(function(acc, cur){
            return acc + cur * 1;
        }, 0);
    });

expect(total).toEqual(600);
```