# Does unary set the variable to its initial value

Tags: javascript, variables, unary-operator

After calculating the result of this code, I wonder if the unary sets my vars as "uno" here to its original state, and if it does, how about negative unaries

```js
let uno = 10, dos = "20", tres = 80;
console.log(++uno + +dos++ + +tres++ - +uno++);
```

my conclusion was the equation of 103, as 11 + 21 + 81 - 10, but it's appearing not to be true!

Comment: and by the way the unary operator `++` after the variable identifier, gets evaluated ***after*** the value of the variable gets considered for the operation involving its value and if put before will be evaulated ***before***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unary operator has lower precedence than the increment operators. So `+dos++` is treated as `+(dos++)`. In this case, the unary operator is redundant, because the increment operator converts the value to a number first (it makes little sense to increment a string).

Since you're using the post-increment operator on `dos` and `tres`, the values of those subexpressions are the original numeric values; see [javascript i++ vs ++i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867876/javascript-i-vs-i). So you're adding `20` and `30`, not `21` and `31`.

When you subtract `uno++` at the end, this happens after the increment from `++uno`. So the value being subtracted is `11`, not `10`.

The entire thing is effectively equivalent to:

```js
let uno = 10, dos = "20", tres = 80;
let uno1 = ++uno; // uno1 = 11, uno = 11
let dos1 = dos++; // dos1 = 20, dos = 21
let tres1 = tres++; // tres1 = 80, tres = 81
let uno2 = uno++; // uno2 = 11, uno = 12
console.log(uno1 + dos1 + tres1 - uno2); // 11 + 20 + 80 - 11 = 100
```