# Increment a value inside a template literal in JS?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to increment a number in a Template Literal in JS, but instead of incrementing the number, it's printing it. Here's the code:

### Code:

```js
function outputFAQResults(results) {
    
        if(results.faqs) {
            const gridClass = results.faqs.length > 1 ? "grid-2" : "grid-1";
            let count = 1 // Here's the number I want to increment in a map loop

            return `
        <div data-result-type="faqs" class="accordion">
            <h2 class="grid-item-heading gold-line">FAQ's</h2>
            <div class="search-results-section">
                <ul class="${gridClass} found-results list-reset">${results.faqs.map((item) => `
                    <li class="search-result search-result--faq" tabindex="0">
                        <div class="search-result__question"><button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#faq-${count}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="faq-${count}">${item.question}</button></div>
                        <div id="faq-${count}" class="search-result__answer collapse">${item.answer}</div>
                    </li>`${count++}).join("")}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>`} else {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

As you can see, for every map, I'm trying to increase the `count` variable by one so I can use a Bootstrap Collapse. How can I use the variable without printing it?

Comment: Is it printing the `++`?

Comment: You mean you want it to first increment it then print it out? You can do ++count. Because that's what template literal should do.

Comment: I really just want to increment the count after a `map` loop - similar to a `foreach` loop. It's just printing "1" at the end of the `<li>`

Comment: You might be interested in examining the behaviour of `\`${count} ${count++}\`` and `\`${count++} ${count}\``  But if not then you can use `,''` in your expression.

Comment: @digitalniweb the `++count` worked! Now off to research the difference.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867876/javascript-i-vs-i for the difference

Comment: BTW, there's no need for the `count` variable. `map()` passes the array index as the second argument to the callback. You can just use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to increment the variable but not output it, don't put it inside the template literal. Change the

```
results.faqs.map((item) => `
  <li class="search-result search-result--faq" tabindex="0">
    <div class="search-result__question"><button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#faq-${count}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="faq-${count}">${item.question}</button></div>
    <div id="faq-${count}" class="search-result__answer collapse">${item.answer}</div>
  </li>`${count++}
).join("")
```

to

```
results.faqs.map((item) => {
  const resultItem = `
    <li class="search-result search-result--faq" tabindex="0">
      <div class="search-result__question"><button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#faq-${count}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="faq-${count}">${item.question}</button></div>
      <div id="faq-${count}" class="search-result__answer collapse">${item.answer}</div>
    </li>`;
  count++;
  return resultItem;
}).join("")
```

However, as mentioned in the comments, there is no reason to have your own counter and increment it. Use the index that is passed as the second argument to your `map` callback:

```
results.faqs.map((item, index) => {
//                      ^^^^^
  const count = index + 1;
  return `
    <li class="search-result search-result--faq" tabindex="0">
      <div class="search-result__question"><button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#faq-${count}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="faq-${count}">${item.question}</button></div>
      <div id="faq-${count}" class="search-result__answer collapse">${item.answer}</div>
    </li>`;
}).join("")
```

Answer (score 0):

`variable++` postfix unary operator result is the previous value of the operand which is definitely is printed by `${}` template interpolation. Use `++variable`, which returns incremented value, on the FIRST occurrence of a variable in a template:

```
results.faqs.map((item) => `
  <li class="search-result search-result--faq" tabindex="0">
    <div class="search-result__question"><button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#faq-${++count}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="faq-${count}">${item.question}</button></div>
    <div id="faq-${count}" class="search-result__answer collapse">${item.answer}</div>
  </li>`
).join("")
```